# What sort of functionality can I expect from exporting a Microsoft Access 2007 Database to a WSS 3.0 site?

Tags: wss-3.0

I have a MS Access 2007 database and a WSS 3.0 site (neither of which I am very experienced in).  The database is currently stored on a shared drive with users remoting in to work with it.  In an effort to improve usability and performance, I want to host this db on my WSS 3.0 site.  Is this feasible?  I need to be able to access and edit data using forms, as well as run reports, all through the UI of the sharepoint site.

Answer (score 2):

Also, remember that you must create a *.**accde**, rather than leave it as **accdb**. The accde is somewhat compiled (queries and code modules are hidden), and the only thing users can manipulate is the actual data. They cannot edit forms/reports/etc.

**accdb** is the standard filetype, and accde is created via the Database Tools ribbon. accdb is one of the default restricted file extensions in Central Admin. You can change it if you want, but personally I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly [store your Access databases](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/publish-a-database-to-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131469.aspx) in your WSS 3.0 site. But users will still need their own copy of Access to open the database.

Also note that even in SharePoint 2010 [Access Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748653.aspx) will allow users to open databases, but they still need the Access client software to modify them.